# C# Socket Client: Understand and Manage messages

Tags: c#, sockets, client

I need to implement a Socket Client in C#.

The socket server is a software connected with my C# client through the port 3000.

Every message is composed as follow:

1. Some fields: 4 bytes
2. Message Length: 2 bytes
3. Some fields: 4 bytes
4. Message Index: 2 bytes
5. Some fields: depends on the 'Message Length' field

When the client Receive, the buffer could contain more the one message and repeated messages.

I have to split the content of the buffer in message, save the message in a list if that message is not already present in this list.

I understand that the message is already present in the list if the index of the message is in the list.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Client
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 3000);


    private void btnC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        sck.Connect(endPoint);

        if (sck.Connected)
        {
            Form1.ActiveForm.Text = Form1.ActiveForm.Text + " - Connected";
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[255];
        int rec;

        while (true)
        {
            buffer = new byte[255];
            rec = sck.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0);
            Array.Resize(ref buffer, rec);


            /* Understand and Manage the messages */


        }
    }
}
 }
```

Have you some suggestion to implement the correct code to understand and manage the received messages ??

Thanks in advance!

Fabio

Comment: I'd start by using `TcpClient` instead of the raw socket, for simplicity. Then just read from the stream - read the amount of data you know about, interpret it, and then read the rest. `BinaryReader` can be very helpful for this.

Comment: You need to look into message framing.

Comment: Using Tcp in a situation like this will yield far more complicated code than what you are anticipating for. For instance it is possible that you receive only a part of a message too. Even only a single byte is possible, so that you don't even know the message length yet just be receiving the first part of it. This is because TCP is a streaming protocol. Use UDP if at all possible in your situation. With UDP you will receive single messages. This design is far more simple. Both for client and server.

Comment: I've generally done this sort of processing using a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). To advance from one state to the next you need to verify that the buffer contains at least one complete piece of information, e.g. a complete 12-byte message header. You keep accumulating data in the buffer and attempting to transition to a new state based on the current state and buffer content. Note that several state transitions may occur as a result of receiving data, e.g. you may have received 3 7/8 new messages.

Comment: Actually your code is quite useless at this point. With TCP sockets, things are connection oriented. You will have one listening socket, in which you call accept which will yield a servicing socket on which you can start to receive data. You will need to start a seperated thread to process that socket and still be prepared to accept new connections on the listinging socket. As I said, TCP is more complex than UDP. UDP is not connection oriented and then your code is much more aline. Because you would have a simple recfrom and that is it.

Comment: As an alternative to starting a new thread you can use the 'select' method on both the listening socket and servicing sockets that you have at any point.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your message like that :

```
public abstract class NetworkMessage
{
    private List<byte> _buffer;

    protected abstract void InternalDeserialize(BinaryReader reader);

    protected NetworkMessage()
    {
        _buffer = new List<byte>();
    }

    public void Deserialize()
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(_buffer.ToArray()))
        {
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
            this.InternalDeserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}

public class YourMessage : NetworkMessage
{
    public int YourField
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override void InternalDeserialize(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        YourField = reader.ReadInt32();
    }
}
```

You have to care about non-blocking network. I mean if you're waiting (with  an infinite time) to receive some data in a button event, you will block your client. There is a lot of tutorials about it :)

And i think that in your "1. Some fields 4 bytes" there is an Id for each messages. You can eventually create a `Dictionnary<id, Networkmessage>` which will return the good message by your id (if you know a bit about reflection, you can create a Func to generate your message) or just a switch. I'm not sure I explained properly what i'm thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario seems most-effectively addressed by wrapping the `Socket` in `NetworkStream`, which in turn may be wrapped by `BinaryReader`. Because you're using this in a Winforms program, you will also want to avoid blocking the UI thread, i.e. don't run the I/O itself in the `btnC_Click()` event handler method.

Unfortunately, the stock `BinaryReader` doesn't offer `async` methods, so the simplest solution is to use synchronous I/O but execute it in a `Task`.

Something like this might work for you (error handling omitted for clarity):

```
// Simple holder for header and data
class Message
{
    public int Field1 { get; private set; }
    public short Length { get; private set; }
    public int Field2 { get; private set; }
    public short Index { get; private set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; private set; }

    public Message(int field1, short length, int field2, int index, byte[] data)
    {
        Field1 = field1;
        Length = length;
        Field2 = field2;
        Index = index;
        Data = data;
    }
}

private void btnC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sck.Connect(endPoint);

    // If Connect() completes without an exception, you're connected
    Form1.ActiveForm.Text = Form1.ActiveForm.Text + " - Connected";

    using (NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(sck))
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        Message message;

        while ((message = await Task.Run(() => ReadMessage(reader))) != null)
        {
            // process message here, preferably asynchronously
        }
    }
}

private Message ReadMessage(BinaryReader reader)
{
    try
    {
        int field1, field2;
        short length, index;
        byte[] data;

        field1 = reader.ReadInt32();
        length = reader.ReadInt16();
        field2 = reader.ReadInt32();
        index = reader.ReadInt16();

        // NOTE: this is the simplest implementation based on the vague
        // description in the question. I assume "length" contains the
        // actual length of the _remaining_ data, but it could be that
        // the number of bytes to read here needs to take into account
        // the number of bytes already read (e.g. maybe this should be
        // "length - 20"). You also might want to create subclasses of
        // Message that are specific to the actual message, and use
        // the BinaryReader to initialize those based on the data read
        // so far and the remaining data.

        data = reader.ReadBytes(length);
    }
    catch (EndOfStreamException)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In general, asynchronous I/O would be better. The above is suitable for a relatively small number of connections. And given that this is the client side, it may well be you have just one connection. So the example I've offered will work fine. But do note that dedicating a single thread to each socket will scale *very* poorly, i.e. it can handle only a relatively small number of connections efficiently.

So keep that in mind if and when you find yourself coding a more elaborate socket scenario. In that case, you'll want to go to the extra trouble of implementing some kind of state-based mechanism that can accumulate data for each message as it comes in over raw byte receives, which you can do using `NetworkStream.ReadAsync()`.

Finally, a couple of notes to address some of the comments you received for the question itself:

- You definitely *do* want to use TCP here. UDP is unreliable – yes, it's message-based, but you also have to deal with the fact that a given message might be received more than once, messages may be received in a different order from that with which they were sent, and messages may not be received at all.

Yes, TCP is stream-oriented which means you have to impose your own message boundaries on it. But that's the only complication as compared to UDP, and otherwise UDP would be *much* more complicated to deal with (unless of course your code inherently does not need reliability…UDP is certainly good for some things, but it's definitely *not* the place to start for a new network programmer).

- There is nothing about your question that suggests you need a "listening" socket. Only one end of a TCP connection needs to be listening; that is the server. You've specifically stated you're implementing the *client*, so listening is not needed. You just need to connect to the server (which your code does).

Answer (score 0):

```
bool getHeader = True;
int header_size = 4+2+4+2;
int payload_size = 0;
byte[] header = new byte[header_size];
byte[] buffer = new byte[255];
int rec;

while (true)
{
    if(getHeader)
    {
        rec = sck.Receive(header, 0, header_size, 0);
        payload_size = ..... parse header[4] & header[5] to payload size (int)
        getHeader = False;
    }else{
        rec = sck.Receive(buffer, 0, payload_size, 0);
        getHeader = True;
    }  
}
```

Comment: should explain what the code does, instead of just dropping it on someone who possibly has no idea how to read it. Let us know that you didn't just copy paste this answer